# Datetime - a week from today

Tags: python, datetime

I am looking into using datetime to find the date one week before now()...
I was wondering if there was a way to use algebraic calculations directly with datetime format?

This is the code I am using.

```
import datetime

def get_week():
    year = datetime.date.today().year
    month = datetime.date.today().month
    day = datetime.date.today().day
    month1 = month
    year1 = year
    day1 = day-7

    if day < 7:
        day1 = 26 # In my case, this date back is plenty enough
        if month == 1:
                month1 = 12
                year1 = year-1

    return year1, month1, day1, year, month, day
```

Comment: Well you *could* do the calculations yourself, or you could use `datetime.timedelta`.

Comment: `datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(7)`

Answer (score 0):

Just use what the `datetime` module offers:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7)

# datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 4, 16, 58, 37, 328226)
```

Comment: Thank you.  Perfect solution.